# `AndAssign`, `OrAssign` (`&&=`, `||=`) in Rust?

Tags: rust, boolean, compound-assignment

Does Rust have a short-circuiting `AndAssign` (`OrAssign`) operator `&&=` (`||=`), or something similar, for `bool`?  These would desugar into:

```rust
// x &&= y
if x { x = y; }

// x ||= y
if !x { x = y; }
```

Is there a shorter way to write these out, or is the longhand the only way?

Comment: No, there is no such operator.

Comment: `x = x && y` is shorter than if statements.

Comment: [`x &= y;`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=05d14dd932e55ccc19c329613f970327) works…

Comment: @Jmb but is [semantically different](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9036b07f155b57cdbc63e35ab59ec742) because it always evaluates `y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing, [there are no compound assignment operations for boolean AND or OR](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#compound-assignment-expressions).

Note however that `if x { x = y; }` can be shortened to `x = x && y` - same with `||`.